# NameError: "name 'x' is not defined"

Tags: python

The problem is my program can't increment variable 'x'.

This is code from the main.py:

```
from functions import increment

x = 1

print('x =',x)
increment()
print('x =',x)
```

This is the code from functions.py:

```
def increment():
    global x
    x += 1
```

And I'm receiving error "name 'x' is not defined". Help, I'm beginner.

Comment: Global variables are almost always a bad idea. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global in the context you put does not work across modules...  if you did something like this, however, it would work

```
globvar = 0

def set_globvar_to_one():
    global globvar    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    globvar = 1

def print_globvar():
    print globvar     # No need for global declaration to read value of globvar

set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()       # Prints 1
```

see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` doesn't be **global** in other modules, if you initial it as **global** in your function ,the global keyword makes a variable global inside its module that been loaded . So you need to simply pass your variable as argument to function and then return the result  :

```
def increment(x):
    x += 1
    return x
```

And in the main code , you can call the function as following :

```
x=increment(x)
```

Comment: Huh? Do you mean `x = increment(x)`? Changing the value inside the function and returning it will not change the original value.